# <v-card> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new in Vuetify and Vue.js.

I try to make v-card layout but failed.

Be honest i copy paste this code :

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/blob/master/src/examples/layouts/centered.vue

And when i run i get error :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-card> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Login> at src/views/Login.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

> I already install vuetify but still error. Any solution ?

**Updated :**

> If i import the vuetify, i get another error : import of entire module
>   vuetify not allowed due to preventFullImport setting

Comment: And have you declared use in your main.js like Vue.use(Vuetify)?

Comment: i get error when import it. import of entire module vuetify not allowed due to preventFullImport setting

Comment: Either you can turn off the setting or you can import the components one by one. Here is the docs for both: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte

Comment: looks like i add vuetify in a la carte mode, so i can't import all right? i must import one by one component of vuetify ?

Comment: It is your choice: if you want to add the whole module, set the preventFullImport to false. If I were you, I would import the full bundle because the code that you copied and pasted contains a lot of Vuetify components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you used the vue-cli-3, you probably had the choice at some point to choose between "à la carte" or full import. You can either, use it to import the components you need or remove "à la carte" :

- Import vcard component in `src/plugins/vuetify.js` with something like :

  ```
  import Vue from "vue";
  import {
      Vuetify,
      VApp,
      VCard,
      /* other imports ... */
  } from "vuetify";
  import "vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl";

  Vue.use(Vuetify, {
      components: {
          VApp,
          VCard,
         /* other imports */
      },
      /* theme option */
  });
  ```
- Remove the "à la carte" import by modifying the `/babel.config.js` file :

  ```
  plugins: [
      [
        "transform-imports",
        {
          vuetify: {
            transform: "vuetify/es5/components/${member}",
            /* change the preventFullImport property to false */
            preventFullImport: true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  ```

Comment: yes you are correct! , i re-add and not select a la carte, and it's works ! Thank you for help.